# Java openConnection calculate progress

Tags: java

I have the following method from which i am trying to update a progressBar as to how far the download has progressed:

```
private void wget(java.net.URL url, String destination) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    java.net.URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    java.io.InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();

    File dstfile = new File(destination);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dstfile);


    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
    int length;
    int readBytes = 0;
    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, length);

        // Get progress
        int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();
        if (contentLength != -1) {

            //System.out.println((length / contentLength) * 100); ??
            UpdateForm.progressBar.setValue(2);
        } else {

        }            
    }

    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

However i cannot seem to figure out how to calculate how many % have gone..

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't reassign `contentLength` every loop iteration. It is a constant. Do it outside the `while`. It will never have a value of `-1`.

Comment: Ahh i see, but how can i get how many % are left?

Comment: When calculating `length`, add it to a sum. Compare that sum to the `contentLength` to get a percentage.

Comment: Not sure i follow what you mean :/

Comment: On each iteration of the loop, you download up to 512 bytes. So, for example, in your third iteration, you would have read 1536 bytes. If your `contentLength` is 40 000 bytes, your percentage complete is `1536 / 40000 = 0.384%`.

Comment: So this should work? `System.out.println((512 / contentLength) * 100);`

Comment: That's always going to give you the same result. Keep another variable `int sum = 0` to which you add `sum += length` on each iteration. Then divide that by `contentLength`.

Comment: Get it now! Thanks a lot man!!